# c# спарсить данные от JS сервера

Tags: javascript, c#, парсер

Здравствуйте, Подскажите, пожалуйста, хочу пройти авторизацию на сайте, но требуется два значения для отправки ПОСТ запроса

token=Hy6U3z61fflbgT2yJ%2FVdlQ2719&

и

uuid=1461931540

. Нашел эти данные в JS файле на сервере /doc/js/asset.7229_12d2ef725908f93d26df0ec0839cd410.js

в коде

```
wp.requestHelper.prototype.setSystemValues = function() {

this.params.data.platform = 'js';
this.params.data.token = 'Hy6U3z61fflbgT2yJ/VdlQ2719'; // TODO: from wp.settings
this.params.data.uuid = parseInt( new Date().getTime() / 1000 + Math.random()*1000, 10);
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить эти данные в переменную C#? 
Ранее использовал только webrequest и webresponse и этого хватало чтобы спарсить данные для авторизации.. А здесь впервые с таким столкнулся... Спасибо.

Comment: А почему не официальное API сайта?

Comment: VladD, подскажите, как это сделать? Он по моему не дает такую возможность.

Comment: Это вам стоит спросить у мейнтейнеров сайта, я даже не знаю, о каком сайте идёт речь.

Comment: А если сайт не предоставляет API? Нет способов достать эти переменные?

Comment: Если сайт не предоставляет API, то он не хочет, чтобы с него тянули информацию, и значит, это делать не нужно.

Comment: Что мешает вытащить [регулярным выражением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения) вроде `this\.params\.data\.token = '([^']+)';` - делается как-то так: `var rx = new Regex(@"this\.params\.data\.token = '([^']+)';", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);   Match m = rx.Match(строка_с_ответом_сервера);   if(m.Success){Console.WriteLine("token: " + m.Groups[1].Value);}`